# how to use index match to return the values of the Name field into table 1

Tags: excel, indexing, match

i have 2 tables that look like this:

table 1

```
ID (Old and New IDs) | Name
---------
I                    |
II                   |
1                    |
2                    |
```

Table 2

```
New ID | Old ID | Name
1      |   I    |  Name1
2      |   II   |  Name2
```

and I'm trying to use index match to return the name in table 1. 
so if it either finds 1 or I it return Name1 and so on.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: how to use index match or any lookup function to return the values of the Name field into table 1

Comment: That needs to be in the question.

Comment: You need something like: `=INDEX('Table 2'!C:C,IFERROR(MATCH(A2,'Table 2'!A:A,0),MATCH(A2,'Table 2'!B:B,0)))`???

Comment: i edited the title, sorry, english is like a second language i couldn't write it better than this.
DIrk, thanks a lot, this works. i can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Dirk Reichel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5461205/dirk-reichel), this answer works:

You need something like: =INDEX('Table 2'!C:C,IFERROR(MATCH(A2,'Table 2'!A:A,0),MATCH(A2,'Table 2'!B:B,0)))